# How can I run html files in tomcat server?

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm studying jsp/servlet. There is no issue running jsp files, but I can't run html files. (404 error, cannot find resources)
I can run through alt+f2 (open in a local file) , the code works well though. The problem occurs only on the browser URL. any idea about this?? I'm using IntelliJ ultimate.
[404 error, can't find resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c2NQ.png)
this is my file directory
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BZZi.png)

This is my web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.example.MyServlet1</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/weburl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>if.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

tried to map html file like this but the same error occurs

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>if</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/if.html</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>if</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/if.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: if your project is `demoweb`  , your url in tomcat will be `http://localhost:8080/demoweb/`

Comment: @life888888 Thank you for reply!, I tried but only the html files occurs 404 error. and also that html files and other jsp files are in the same location but, only jsp files works.

Comment: What is the `if` servlet? I don't see a definition in your question. You should not define a `default` servlet, unless you (a) `extend DefaultServlet` and (b) really know what you are doing. You should not have to specifically map every .html file you have; the (real) DefaultServlet should handle that for you.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I know I should not map every html files. but at that time I was suffering even just the normal html file had problem opening. idk why this happens. so i did every dumb things just to resolve it. so I just made a new project and moved all those files to my new project and it solved. seems there's an issue about project structure ig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all show me your error, it's browser error or it's tomcat server error like (404- not found).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>if</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/if.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>if</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/if.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Error in this code, at last line on file location.

Comment: Oh I rebooted and it works. thank you for your reply! I have a question. Should I have to map all the html file one by one to run?? then, why do I have to map? I thought html extension files are root file of jsp extension files. and jsp files don't need to map in web.xml.